# SequenceEncoder encodeImage return an error

Tags: java, android, video, screenshot, encode

I'm making a video out of screenshots. I have try chatches done.

Here I initialized my encoder.

```
String filename = "video.mp4";
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
enc = new SequenceEncoder(file);
```

This gets a screenshots.

```
public Bitmap getScreenShot() {
    View screenView = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    Bitmap bitmap = screenView.getDrawingCache();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

This how I encoded image. and it returns an exception.

```
enc.encodeImage(getScreenShot());
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.jcodec.common.model.Picture.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Comment: do you test `getScreenShot()` that it returns some valid image and not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I asked for a screenshot of my layout in the wrong time, so getScreenShot() returns a null bitmap.

I solved it by calling it from on onWindowFocusChanged instead of onCreate.